# Cannot complete SSL handshake with gateway.push.apple.com using perl IO::Socket::SSL

Tags: perl, sockets, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am very new to this type of thing and not sure what I am doing wrong.

Inside Mojolicious app, I am battling to connect to the Apple Push Notification SSL Socket. I would like to send a push notification to an app.

Debug Information:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2700: new ctx 138351632
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:612: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:614: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:636: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:669: using SNI with hostname gateway.push.apple.com
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:704: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:736: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2601: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2554: ok=0 [1] /O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification     Authority (2048)/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:739: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:742: SSL connect attempt failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:742: local error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:745: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: ...5.18/IO/Socket.pm:48: ignoring less severe local error 'IO::Socket::IP configuration failed', keep 'SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL     routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2733: free ctx 138351632 open=138351632
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2738: free ctx 138351632 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2745: OK free ctx 138351632
```

Code snip bit:

```
use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);

my $cl = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
  PeerHost => 'gateway.push.apple.com',
  # PeerHost => 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
  PeerPort => '2195',
  SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER,
  SSL_ca_file => '/var/www/foo/bar/cert/ck.pem',
);
```

I'm not sure where to go or what to do from here?

Comment: problem with your ssl certificate in the server- side. check out the ssl certificate is valid or not?

Comment: My guess is that `/var/www/foo/bar/cert/ck.pem` does not contain the CA which signed the certificate you got from the server. But it is hard to tell without knowing the contents of this file.

Comment: Apart from that I think that this service needs a client certificate which you need to specify with SSL_cert_file and SSL_key_file.

Comment: I figured it out: I was using the incorrect pass phrase!
I was able to implement the much simpler perl module `Net::APNS`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: I was using the incorrect pass phrase! I was able to implement the much simpler perl module `Net::APNS`

```
use Net::APNS;

my %settings = (
  cert   => "$Cert_file",
  key    => "$Cert_key_file",
  passwd => "$passphrase",
);

if(my $Notifier = Net::APNS->new->notify(\%settings)) {
  $Notifier->write({
    devicetoken => "$device_token",
    message     => "$message",
    sound       => 'default',
    badge       => 1
  });

  return 1 if defined($Notifier) and ref($Notifier) eq "Net::APNS::Notification";
}
```

Thank you for all your input!